# What is the fastest way to left shift the n least significant bits of a number in c++

Tags: binary, bit-shift

I have this binary number:

```
00000111
```

how I can compute

```
11100000
```

meaning left shifting the 3 least significant bits?
In this case all are 1's but it might be any n binary digits

Comment: Use the left bit shift operator ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work